# SharePoint Online: Email alerts not working when using Mail enabled Security groups in Dev instance

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an office 365 developer tenancy. I wanted to try the option of Email alerts through the Mail enabled Security groups.

I have created a new Mail-enabled security group(AlertTest) and added few users to the group. My site structure has unique permissions at all levels.

So I have added the "AlertTest" group to SharePoint Security groups which have read access at the Site collection level, subsite level and also at the library level.

And then created an alert for the "AlertTest" group on the library. But it didn't send out the even the subscription notification to the members of the group

Answer (score 1):

We did follow the [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2412093/users-don-t-receive-sharepoint-online-alert-notifications). But still we haven't received the notifications. After going through different things, We were able to find out what was wrong. The issue was with the mail enabled security group. When you create a mail enabled security group in O365 by default it is created with the setting to allow 'Only Senders inside my organization'. This was the reason why we didnt get the notifications as SharePoint is sending its email from no-reply@sharepointonline.com which o365 consider it as different domain. Once we change this setting it was all good.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, follow these steps:

1. Investigate the user's permissions for the list, for the library, or for the task list. Make sure that the user account has at least Read permissions on the object.

   - If these permissions are present, go to step 2.
   - If these permissions aren't present, direct the user to the site administrator to have these permissions corrected.
2. Verify that new alerts work. To do this, create a new alert on a test library or on a test list. Perform an action to generate the alert. For example, add, edit, or delete an item. Then, wait 15 minutes. If the alert isn't received, collect the following information, and then contact Microsoft Office 365 technical support:

   - Verify the last known time that alerts were received.
   - Record the exact steps to reproduce the issue in the new alert.

About the detail steps, you can follow [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2412093/users-don-t-receive-sharepoint-online-alert-notifications) article.